# Google Finance API

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api, google-finance-api

I am trying to test the price from "l" in the get request to the url http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:AAPL

This is my code. I keep getting error JSONError: Unexpected token '/' at 2:1 // [ ^

```
var jsonData = [];
jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
jsonData = jsonData.Replace("//","");
tests["Google Stock"] = jsonData["l"] === 157.50;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're running JSON.parse on the responseBody, that starts with '//' ... you simply need to  replace the first 3 lines with this

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody.replace('//', '');
```

Note: it's `replace` not `Replace`

and then

```
tests["Google Stock"] = jsonData[0]["l"] === 157.50;
```

because the data is an array of objects (single item, but still an array) -the above is better written

```
tests["Google Stock"] = jsonData[0].l === 157.50;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. Also had to change it to "157.50" with quotes